# Force rotate a certain log file without using logrotate

Tags: bash, logging

I am trying to force rotate a specific log, e.g., `/mroot/etc/mlog/sktrace.log`.

For example, currently here are all the logs related to sktrace:

```
<machine_name>% ll /mroot/etc/mlog/sktrace*
-rw-r--r--  2 root  wheel   13276789 Oct 16 13:00 /mroot/etc/mlog/sktrace.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    3063670 Oct 13 10:42 /mroot/etc/mlog/sktrace.log.0000000001
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   44072508 Oct 14 10:42 /mroot/etc/mlog/sktrace.log.0000000002
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   96622284 Oct 15 10:42 /mroot/etc/mlog/sktrace.log.0000000003
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  104858396 Oct 16 08:54 /mroot/etc/mlog/sktrace.log.0000000004
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   10466192 Oct 16 10:42 /mroot/etc/mlog/sktrace.log.0000000005
-rw-r--r--  2 root  wheel   13276789 Oct 16 13:00 /mroot/etc/mlog/sktrace.log.0000000006
```

By “force rotate”, I mean to copy the content in the current `/mroot/etc/mlog/sktrace.log` to `/mroot/etc/mlog/sktrace.log.0000000007`, and then truncate `/mroot/etc/mlog/sktrace.log` to 0-byte.

The decent way is probably via `logrotate`. But it is not available on the system I am using:

```
<machine_name>% which logrotate
logrotate: Command not found.
<machine_name>% ll /usr/sbin/logrotate
ls: /usr/sbin/logrotate: No such file or directory
```

What's the best alternative in `bash`, please?

Comment: Have you considered building `logrotate` yourself? https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate

Comment: @janos No, I don't have that permission on the system.

Comment: Log rotation doesn't usually work by copying and truncating. It's usually done by renaming the current file, then sending a signal to the process telling it to open a new file.

Comment: Also, usually `.log.1` is the most recent, not the oldest. So rotation renames `.1` to `.2`, `.2` to `.3`, etc. Then renames `.log` to `.log.1` and signals the process.

Comment: @QiangXu when you build from source, you can install them in your home directory. No special permissions needed. You do need some build tools though. If they are not available in the target system, then you can build on another system, and copy over to the target. But I'm getting the feeling you might not be up for all this, though it's totally doable.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the reminder. I didn't know that the naming convention for the rotated log files on our system is different from the standard one.

Comment: What do you mean by "force rotate"? Is there something that's already rotating them automatically, and you want to force it to happen on demand?

Comment: @Barmar From the list of the log files, clearly there is something already rotating them, based on some criteria that I don't know. Yes, I want to force it to happen one way or another "on demand", regardless the time interval or the size of the current log copy.

Comment: You should find out what's doing it, it may already have a way to trigger it.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. I guess you are right. Will try to find which process is managing these log files.